# rails has_many multiple single table inheritance

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many, single-table-inheritance

I have a couple base models, `Post` and `Comment`, with a `post` having many `comment`s:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to: :post
end
```

I also have single table inheritance on each of these models, with the child classes not having their own database tables.  I have `type` columns in the `posts` and `comments` tables.

```
class ChildPost < Post
    has_many :child_comments, class_name: "Comment"
end

class ChildComment < Comment
    belongs_to :child_post, class_name: "ChildPost"
end
```

Now if I create some of these objects

```
child_comment = ChildComment.create
child_post = ChildPost.create
child_post.child_comments << child_comment
child_post.save
```

When I do `child_post.child_comments` I get:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column comments.child_post_id does not exist
```

It's correct that the column `child_post_id` doesn't exist (it's `post_id`), but what do I need to do to correct this?

In terms of design, I've set things up this way because the data of a `child_comment` and a `comment` are the same, but they have slightly different behavior.  I want `ChildComment` to override only some methods of `Comment`.  And I want a `comment` and `child_comment` to be distinguishable database entries.

If there's a better design here, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify both `:class_name` and `:foreign_key` in your `has_many` association:

```
has_many :child_comments, class_name: "Comment", :foreign_key => "post_id"
```

The `:foreign_key` option lets you set the name of the foreign key directly. So, if you set that to `post_id`, then it will work because `post_id` column is present in the `comments` table.

Comment: @K M Rakibul Islam - specifying the `foreign_key`- right.  It ended up that the ChildPost class needed:
    has_many :child_comments, foreign_key: "post_id"

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @johnnyh I have updated my answer. Please consider accepting the answer if that solved your problem.